# OpenSearch - Sum Amount from array grouped by key

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I want to create an Table Visualization in OpenSearch which sums the amount of diffrenz items grouped by the hash of the item.

The raw data looks like:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "fieldH": "example",
    "items": [
      {
        "hash": "item1",
        "amount": 2
      },
      {
        "hash": "item2",
        "amount": 3
      }
    ],
    "date": "2023-01-20T11:08:35.960Z"
  }
}
{
  "_source": {
    "fieldH": "example",
    "items": [
      {
        "hash": "item2",
        "amount": 5
      },
      {
        "hash": "item3",
        "amount": 3
      }
    ],
    "date": "2023-01-20T11:08:35.960Z"
  }
}
```

currently it looks like:
(bcs it sums all amounts which are in the found document)

| Item Hash | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | 5 |
| Item2 | 13 |
| Item3 | 8 |

The result should look like:

| Item Hash | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | 2 |
| Item2 | 8 |
| Item3 | 3 |

Visualisation Settings Looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50vew.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmPIE.png)

Does somebody knows how to handle this?

Comment: I believe the `nested` field type can solve your problem.

https://opensearch.org/docs/1.3/opensearch/supported-field-types/nested/

Comment: With nested field type, you can create aggregation query and you will get correct results. Unfortunately, you can just use **VEGA** to create the visualization. Here is an example article for you.

https://mafiaguy.medium.com/how-to-create-a-visualization-for-nested-objects-templates-ed2c42facb6d